# Interpreting Land Record Abstract pre-1730 Pennsylvania?

Tags: united-states, 18th-century, pennsylvania, will, land

I am researching the 4 generations of my family that arrived in Chester County Pennsylvania between 1682-1715. In order to get a fuller picture of these ancestors, I've just begun looking through the land record abstracts in *Abstracts of Chester County Pennsylvania Land Records Vol. 1 1681-1730, Author Carol Bryant*.

Here is the relevant text from Land Records Vol. 1: ***Bond.*** Isaac Few & Julian Few of the county of Chester, executors of the will of Richard Few, late of Chester county **are holden & firmly bound** to **Thomas Brassey & Caleb Pussey** of Chester county, yeomen for 500 pounds. Signed Isaac Few & Julian Few. **Delivered** in the presence of George Churchman, Henry Brassey & Lawrence Routh. Recorded 16 Aug 1678. (A1:B58)

**Questions**

1. What is the definition of Bond in this context? (I haven't been able to find a definition for 'Bond' in this context via google.)
2. I presume that Richard Few bought his land from Thomas Brassey and Caleb Pussey, and still owed them 500 pounds at the time of his death. Is that right?
3. (re: *'are holden & firmly bound'*) Have Isaac Few & Julian Few personally taken on the debt that Richard Few had with Brassey and Pussey? Or is it likely that it was paid out of Richard Few's estate?
4. Since the word 'Delivered' is used, does that indicate that Isaac & Julian paid the debt on the spot?
5. What does 'Recorded 16 Aug 1678' refer to?

**Notes**

1. I've tried to locate the will for Richard Few. I haven't found one yet, which led me to try looking at the land records instead...
2. I did find an abstract for the will of a Isaac Few. In it Isaac Few renounces his son Richard Few. (My guess is that the Isaac Few referenced in the Land Records is a brother or son of Richard Few...)

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than many questions in one.  If you have multiple questions then you can always ask them in separate questions and start them with a link to the question that contains any background that is relevant to all of them.

Comment: Surely we don't have enough information to answer the question? We don't know what the Bond actually commits anyone to? Experts in these types of documents may, however, know what these bonds were typically about. As an example, the £500 might be a penalty to be paid by the Fews to Brassey and Pussey if they don't do something, rather than an outstanding purchase price. But I'm speculating to show that, so far as I can see, we don't know enough. Possibly...